# selenium-Python help, can not find element by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The html is below:

```
<td>
      <a href="JavaScript: void(0);" onclick="submitAction(document.bfcm003s, 'bfcm003s204'); return false;">
        <img src="../images/menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu04_n.jpg" alt="search by NO" width="131" height="34" border="0">
      </a>
 </td>
```

my python code:

```
imgs = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/@src="../images/menu_buttonssub_bnyushu04_n.jpg"]')
```

but it said the code could not find any element by this xpath.

any ideas for this?

Comment: This seem to be a simple typo: you missed slash in `menu_buttonssub_bnyushu04_n.jpg`...it should be `menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu04_n.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this *xpath*:

```
//a/img[@src="../images/menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu04_n.jpg"]
```

Test with `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring("""<td>
      <a href="JavaScript: void(0);" onclick="submitAction(document.bfcm003s, 'bfcm003s204'); return false;">
        <img src="../images/menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu04_n.jpg" alt="search by NO" width="131" height="34" border="0"/>
      </a>
 </td>""")   

# extract the width attribute of the img node
tree.xpath('//a/img[@src="../images/menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu04_n.jpg"]/@width')
# ['131']
```

Comment: Hi, Psidom. Thank you for your idea. i have tried your way on my end, but it does not work.

Comment: Please try this xpath:  //img[contains(@src, 'menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu') and @alt='search by NO']

Comment: Thanks @Monika, i have tried this code `imgs = [tag for tag in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu') and @alt== u'物件番号検索']")]` (this page is a Japanese page). but it said it is not a valid xpath expression.

Comment: If it is Japanese page, you can use the xpath:  //img[contains(@src, 'menu_buttons/sub_bnyushu') ]

Comment: @YamPakChing, you should use `=` operator in `XPath` predicate to compare values, not `==`! So try `@alt=u'物件番号検索'`

Comment: Hi @Monika , Thank you for your help. I have already resolved this problem with your idea. Thank you.

Comment: Hi , @Andersson, Thank you for telling me that.